# VBA Superscript Excel

Tags: excel, vba, superscript

I am looking to create a macro to increase the number of the superscript. If I have a cell a12 with 12 in superscript I would want it to make it 13. What I have currently will only do this with numbers but not if there is text attached to it.

```
Sub Up_One() 
    ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value + 1 
End Sub 

Sub Down_One() 
    ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value - 1 
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you only have one number that's superscript, or can your cell be `a12b13` for example with the `13` superscript as well?

Comment: Typically I'd only have one number in the cell.  I'm looking to use it for footnote indicators so I'd have text and then the footnote number at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating footnotes (so your superscript numbers are at the end), then perhaps something like this, which

- Loops over the characters in the cell, starting from the end.
- Exits the loop once it hits a character that's not superscript, otherwise stores the characters in a temporary variable.
- Checks if the temporary variable is a number, and if so, increments by one.
- Replaces the old number with the new one.
- Reapplies the superscript formatting.

```
Sub IncrementFootnote()

    With ActiveCell
        If .HasFormula Or TypeName(.Value) <> "String" Then Exit Sub

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ' extract superscript text, starting from the end
        Dim i As Long
        For i = .Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript Then
                Dim temp As String
                temp = .Characters(i, 1).Text & temp
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

       ' if a number, increment, replace the old number, and superscript
        If IsNumeric(temp) Then
            Dim newNumber
            newNumber = temp + 1

            .Replace temp, newNumber

            Dim pos As Long
            pos = InStrRev(.Value, newNumber)

            .Characters(pos, Len(newNumber)).Font.Superscript = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

For subtracting one, just change `newNumber = temp + 1` to `newNumber = temp - 1`.

Note that the

```
If .HasFormula Or TypeName(.Value) <> "String" Then Exit Sub
```

checks if the cell is truly text, so it will skip formulas, as well as *just numbers only*.

[image]